# Transfer an image file of more than 5GB

Tags: ubuntu-one, files

I am trying to upload an image file of about 5-6 GB. I therefore bought more space on my cloud but when trying to upload the file it does not work. Why? have tried with Safari and Firefox, same result, uploading appears but no data transfer. Thank you. Frederic

Comment: What is the reason you don't put the file in your Ubuntu One directory? (assuming there is a reason) – note also, just a small tip, you can use `u1sdtool` on the command-line to watch what Ubuntu One is doing, if you're using the Ubuntu One client instead of the web-interface.

Answer (score 2):

Check with ubuntuone support to see if you are exceeding the maximum file size limit, I believe the maximum file size for sync is 5GB for the basic account if this is the same for files that can be uploaded with your paid account, this could be the problem.

Whenever you use a browser to upload files to ubuntuone the file upload dialogue may not have any progress report, the upload button text just changes to uploading.

your file is large, depending on your bandwidth you may have to wait a long time before you can tell if the file has uploaded, try with a small file to see quickly if things are working.

You can try the chromium browser from the repositories, and notice the status bar, lower left corner, there is a percent upload report there.

The next thing to consider is that you can place the file in your ubuntuone folder or just place it in a folder you created and then sync (This assumes Ubuntu 10.04 or 10.1) that folder with ubuntuone. If it turns out that your file is too large for syncing you will have to find a way to reduce its size or do a split.

Comment: the 5GB limit has been lifted to 5TB, so you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you can't upload a 5gb file via the web browser. There are plenty of limitations on the browsers and server side that would make this impossible.

The only way to upload such a huge file would be using the desktop client, which has built-in support for dealing with large files.